# A nested resource cannot appear inside of a resource with a for-expression

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

I want to generate an ESB with bicep and several topics. Each topic could have one or more subscriptions. These are defined inside this list.

```
var topics = [{
  name: 'topic.one'
  subscriptions: [ 'esm', 'erp', 'pms' ]
}, {
  name: 'topic.two'
  subscriptions: [ 'esm' ]
}, {
  name: 'topic.three'
  subscriptions: [ 'erp', 'insights' ]
}, {
  name: 'topic.four'
  subscriptions: [ 'pms', 'cmdb']
}, {
  name: 'topic.five'
  subscriptions: [ 'billing', 'custom', 'erp', 'dax' ]
}]
```

When I create the resource the easiest and most dynamic solution will create a loop inside a loop like below.

```
resource sb_events 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  name: 'servicebus-events'
  location: 'westeurope'
  sku: {
    capacity: 1
    name: 'Standard'
    tier: 'Standard'
  }

  resource topic_resources 'topics' = [for topic in topics: {
    name: topic.name  

    resource subscription_resources 'subscriptions' = [for subscription in topic.subscriptions: {
      name: subscription
      properties: vSubscriptionProperties
    }]
  }]
}
```

But this gives me next error:

> A nested resource cannot appear inside of a resource with a for-expression. bicep(BCP160)

When this code looks logic, the bicep compiler don't accept this. How could I fix this?

Comment: nested loop are not supported in bicep, you could create a module to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bicep does not support nested loop for the moment:

- https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/1280

You could have a module that creates a topic and subscriptions:

```
// sb-topic-and-subscriptions.bicep
param namespaceName string
param topicName string
param subscriptionNames array
param vSubscriptionProperties  object

resource namespace 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces@2022-01-01-preview' existing = {
  name: namespaceName
}

resource topic 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics@2022-01-01-preview' = {
  parent: namespace
  name: topicName

  resource subscriptions 'subscriptions' = [for sub in subscriptionNames: {
    name: sub
    properties: vSubscriptionProperties
  }]
}
```

Then you can invoke it from your main:

```
...
// loop and create all the topics and subscription.
module topicsModule 'sb-topic-and-subscriptions.bicep' = [for topic in topics: {
  name: topic.name
  params: {
    namespaceName: 'servicebus-events'
    subscriptionNames: topic.subscriptions
    topicName:  topic.name
    vSubscriptionProperties: vSubscriptionProperties
  }
}]
```